# Angular - disable a field if it changes

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and my project requires disabling a field if it was changed a number of times (3), but I have not found the logic to perform the disabled, if someone can guide me to come up with a solution I would appreciate it very much...

at the moment of wanting to save it goes through a method that saves it, I know I have to use that method, but I don't know how to put it in the conditional

---

P.S. my version of angular is 9.1.2

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please give more description: How do you define "change"? Do you mean characters input? focused? blured? Also - please show some code you have already tried,,,

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<input [disabled]="changedCount >= 3" type="checkbox" (change)="handleChange()"/>
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-comp',
  templateUrl: './your-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-comp.component.css']
})
export class YourCompComponent implements OnInit {
changeCount: number = 0;
  constructor() { }

 handleChange(){
  this.changeCount++;
 }    

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: Gerome's answer below is a better answer if your are dealing with a reactive form.

Comment: this is your answer. disabling an input field is one of the simplest things to do with angular.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using ReactiveForm :

Define your input in the template :

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="formControl">
```

Inside the component, listen to the changes made upon the input and disable it if 3 changes have been operated :

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  formControl: FormControl = new FormControl('');
  isDisabled$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {
    // listen to changes on the input
    this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      // wait for 500ms if the user is still typing
      debounceTime(500),
      // stop the subscription if 3 changes have been made
      takeUntil(this.isDisabled$),
      // save the number of changes
      scan((acc, arr) => acc += 1 , 0)
    ).subscribe(changes => {
      if (changes > 2) {
      this.isDisabled$.next(true);
      this.formControl.disable();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[Working example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqaquv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Another solution but less accessible for you as your are new to Angular would be to use a custom Directive :

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'input'
})
export class FormMaxChangesDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(@Self() private control: NgControl) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // listen to changes on the input
    this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      // wait for 500ms if the user is still typing
      debounceTime(500),
      // stop the subscription if 3 changes have been made
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      // save the number of changes
      scan((acc, arr) => acc += 1 , 0)
    ).subscribe(changes => {
      if (changes > 2 && this.control.enabled) {
      this.control.control.disable();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(null);
  }

}
```

Its selector is 'input' so it'll work on any input declared in your templates. It'll scale if you have multiple input with the same behavior as you won't have to declare a variable to count the changes per input.

[Working example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sample-form-maxchanges-directive?file=src/app/form-max-changes.directive.ts)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a field change is the time a user had the focus on the field, then change anything in that field and then blurs the field. 
You can listen to the "blur" "focus" and "input" event for the interaction with this field. If the field gets a Focus and the input gets triggert then you can add +1 to a counter in the blur listener. If the counter was changed to 3 in the blur , you disable the input field.

I hope that is what you are searching for.